# Many times value comes when using $.each function loop?

Tags: jquery, json

I am new to Jquery. Now i need to display the Json string value using $.each function.

```
var MyJson = [
{
    "ImageId": "101",
    "ImageURL": "../../uploads/1.jpg",
    "ImageName": "1.jpg"
},
{
    "ImageId": "102",
    "ImageURL": "../../uploads/2.jpg",
    "ImageName": "2.jpg"
},
{
    "ImageId": "103",
    "ImageURL": "../../uploads/3.jpg",
    "ImageName": "3.jpg"
},
{
    "ImageId": "104",
    "ImageURL": "../../uploads/4.jpg",
    "ImageName": "4.jpg"
},
{
    "ImageId": "105",
    "ImageURL": "../../uploads/5.jpg",
    "ImageName": "5.jpg"
}
        ];
```

My Json string is available above and i need to display the each image once.

```
var $template = $('.pics');

        $(MyJson).each(function () {

            var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
            innerDiv.className = 'pics';
            GalleryPics.appendChild(innerDiv);
            $(".pics").each(function (i) {
                $(this).append("<a href='" + MyJson[i].ImageURL + "' rel='lightbox-journey'><img src='" + MyJson[i].ImageURL + "' width='150' height='150' /></a>");
            });
        });
```

Using this code, i can make it to display all images, the first images is displaying for 5 times and second image is displaying for 4 times and so on like this. So please help me to avoid those duplication and display all the images once.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Whats `GalleryPics` and what is the `$(".pics").each()` block supposed to be doing?

Comment: GalleryPics is a div which i need to put all the images into that div, and all the images should also have div with its name called ".pics"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

**JS**

```
$(MyJson).each(function (obj) {
    $("#GalleryPics").append("<div class='pics'><a href='" + obj.ImageURL + "' rel='lightbox-journey'><img src='" + obj.ImageURL + "' width='150' height='150' /></a></div>");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="GalleryPics"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EcC9C/

Answer (score 1):

You keep using `$(".pics")` which will include *all* the divs with that classname.

Append the anchor tag to the div you created, not all the divs with the `pics` class.

Comment: Sorry I couldnt get you as i am beginner. Please can you rewrite my code.

Comment: @AdmireAnanth When you run `$(".pics")` you will return all the DOM elements with the `pics` class. You are *adding* elements with the `pics` class, so each time through the loop, you get additional elements. You don't want to add the anchor tag to *all* the elements, only the one you just created.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Here it is looping 5 times, because you have 5 objects in your array
        $(MyJson).each(function () {
//Here it is looping over all your .pics elements.
        $(".pics").each(function (i) {
            $(this).append("<a href='" + MyJson[i].ImageURL + "' rel='lightbox-journey'><img src='" + MyJson[i].ImageURL + "' width='150' height='150' /></a>");
        });
    });
```

I can't say for certain what you need since i don't know if the number of .pics elements is the same as the number of objects in your json.
You only need one loop.  something like below. Except you should quit if i > MyJson.length.

```
 $(".pics").each(function (i) {
            $(this).append("<a href='" + MyJson[i].ImageURL + "' rel='lightbox-    journey'><img src='" + MyJson[i].ImageURL + "' width='150' height='150' /></a>");
});
```